# Parse and Uber API Webhooks

Tags: parse-platform, webhooks, uber-api

I’m building an iOS app that utilizes Uber’s API and Parse. After a user requests a ride in my app and the ride status changes, I’d like to update the in app screen and send a push notification. Uber’s docs say to use web hooks for this. I’m trying to figure out how I would do this if I’m using Parse. As far as I know, a Parse backend doesn’t have the ability to receive POST data from the Uber web hooks. I was thinking of making a small express server that would receive the web hooks POST data, clean it up, and send it to Parse’s API which would in turn send it to the client as a push notification. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. It looks like there are some projects in the [Parse OpenSource Hub](https://parseplatform.github.io/) you could re-use for your purpose.

The alternative is to simply do a [`GET /v1/requests/current`](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-current) every few seconds within your app.